# Using sed to pull a value from an XML file, and I get whitespace at the beginning. How can I avoid that?

Tags: bash, sed

I'm using sed to put a value contained in an XML file into a variable.

The file looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DataBase>
        <DataBaseName>fry</DataBaseName>
</DataBase>
```

I'm doing this:

```
dbName=$(sed -n 's|<DataBaseName>\(.*\)</DataBaseName>|\1|p' path/to/DataBase.xml)
```

And it grabs fry correctly, however it has a tab at the beginning. What am I doing wrong in my sed command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
dbName=$(sed -n 's|\s*<DataBaseName>\(.*\)</DataBaseName>|\1|p' path/to/DataBase.xml)
```

(You need to match the *possible* whitespace characters, too.

Answer (score 0):

You are not matching complete line.

Try this:

```
dbName=$(sed -n 's|[ \t]*<DataBaseName>\(.*\)</DataBaseName>|\1|p' path/to/DataBase.xml)
```

By skipping `tabs` and `spaces`, only `<DataBaseName>` and `</DataBaseName>` are removed from line. All other characters remain. Check this [tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) for more.

For example, if you modify your file to:

```
<DataBaseName>fry</DataBaseName>something
```

This command:

```
sed -n 's|[ \t]*<DataBaseName>\(.*\)</DataBaseName>|\1|p' sed_file
```

will output:

```
frysomething
```

simply because your regex didn't matched `something`.